# In OpenCV should I round the CAP_PROP_FPS value for use in cv2.waitKey()

Tags: opencv

I'm just getting started with video and OpenCV so I am working my way through some basic coding examples. 
If I VideoCapture ("MyFile.mov") to load a video into OpenCV and then get the property CAP_PROP_FPS I get a value 24.998291482797672

Is it advisable to use that specific value or should I round up to 25?

Also, is the value 
`24.998291482797672`a result of some decision made when producing the video and a result of some specific hardware and software combinations or is it more global and known as the more precise value for 25 fps video files?

Update: I evaluated a number of my source videos and most are 25 fps but 2 have fps rates that would round to 25 but are reported as 24.xyz to 10 decimal points.  I just added it for information, if someone does know why / how they could end up with frame rates of slightly less than 25

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably just a rounding error or something, there's like a single frame worth of difference at 9 minutes of video. Unless you're doing a very long video, you won't be able to see a difference at all. I can't think of anything that specifies 24.998 as opposed to 25. Personally, I'd suggest sticking with the 25.

Comment: Is it important for your application that the playback is super-precise?

Comment: Does machine learning need super precision? My file is just over 1 hr but I have to break it down into segments yet so maybe its not too critical but would prefer to start the right way.

Comment: For machine learning, you may not need the waitKey().  Also, what are you planning to use the learning for?

Comment: Considering that `waitKey()` usually uses sleep, so it really waits _at least that many ms_ the rounding error is irrelevant in your example (it will be fractions of a millisecond). Furthermore, there will very likely be overhead outside of `waitKey()`, so even if it waited exactly the time determined from the frame rate, your playback would lag due to that overhead which you don't account for. If you want to play back at correct speed, you need to keep track of the real time elapsed in processing (and drawing to the window), and wait just the time remaining to next frame "tick".

Comment: @Ulrich I'm planning on training SVM, Random Forrest and ANN on the data once I get a grip of it myself

Comment: I used CNNs to analyze animal behavior in videos, getting to about human performance level (see [paper](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep14351)).  In my case, looking at single frames was sufficient to recognize what we were interested in.  I had some variation in my videos (e.g., focal plane, exposure level), and the CNNs handled (learned to "ignore") this variation easily, unlike the heuristics I tried before switching to CNNs.